# Loud fan noise on ubuntu 14.04 - Alienware x51 i3 desktop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, overheating, fan, alienware

I have a really loud fan on my alienware x51 i3 desktop running ubuntu 14.04. I thought it was a driver issue, so changed driver from open source to a proprietary driver - but not driver changes have helped.

Sometimes the fan is quiet - I have noticed that this is when the opening 'Alienware' screen (link to a pic below) does not flash on startup. When it does flash on startup, the computer fans are loud. Also when the PC hasn't been used for some time e.g. a week, the fans are quiet when it is first used.

System assessment tests show these results:

- CPU thermistor - 62 degC
- Power thermistor - 36 degC
- CPU Fan - 941 RPM
- Sys Fan - 1123 RPM
- Power Fan - 2439 RPM

I run BIOS version A03

Thank you for any ideas about helping to solve this issue :)

link to opening alienware screen:
http://www.jagatreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/alienware-x51-startup-screen.jpg